# Flutter 3.7.5 Resolving dependencies error

Tags: flutter, dependencies, upgrade

I just updated flutter to 3.7.5 from 3.3.10.

Now every time I run flutter pub get its showing Resolving dependencies.
Running "flutter pub get" in test1...

```
  characters 1.2.1 (1.3.0 available)
  collection 1.17.0 (1.17.1 available)
  connectivity 3.0.6 (discontinued)
  country_code_picker 2.0.2 (discontinued)
  dbus 0.5.4 (0.7.8 available)
  flutter_launcher_icons 0.11.0 (0.12.0 available)
  flutter_layout_grid 1.0.6 (2.0.1 available)
  flutter_local_notifications 9.1.4 (13.0.0 available)
  flutter_local_notifications_linux 0.3.0 (3.0.0+1 available)
  flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface 5.0.0 (6.0.0 available)
  flutter_math_fork 0.5.0 (0.6.3+1 available)
  flutter_svg 0.23.0+1 (2.0.2 available)
  image 3.1.3 (4.0.15 available)
  intl 0.17.0 (0.18.0 available)
  js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
  matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.14 available)
  meta 1.8.0 (1.9.0 available)
  month_picker_dialog_2 0.6.2+1 (discontinued replaced by month_picker_dialog)
  numerus 1.1.1 (2.0.0 available)
  package_info_plus 1.4.3+1 (3.0.3 available)
  package_info_plus_linux 1.0.5 (2.0.0 available)
  package_info_plus_macos 1.3.0 (2.0.0 available)
  package_info_plus_platform_interface 1.0.2 (2.0.1 available)
  package_info_plus_web 1.0.6 (2.0.0 available)
  package_info_plus_windows 2.1.0 (3.0.0 available)
  path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
  path_drawing 0.5.1+1 (1.0.1 available)
  path_parsing 0.2.1 (1.0.1 available)
  petitparser 5.1.0 (5.2.0 available)
  pinput 1.2.2 (2.2.31 available)
  rive 0.9.1 (0.10.2 available)
  share 2.0.4 (discontinued)
  test_api 0.4.16 (0.4.18 available)
  timezone 0.8.0 (0.9.1 available)
  upgrader 3.11.1 (6.0.1 available)
  version 2.0.3 (3.0.2 available)
  webview_flutter 2.8.0 (4.0.5 available)
  webview_flutter_android 2.10.4 (3.3.1 available)
  webview_flutter_platform_interface 1.9.5 (2.0.2 available)
  webview_flutter_wkwebview 2.9.5 (3.1.1 available)
  win32 3.1.3 (4.1.1 available)
  xdg_directories 0.2.0+3 (1.0.0 available)
  xml 5.4.1 (6.2.2 available)Got dependencies!
```

when I'm compiling app showing following error

: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
.push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(

```
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
  ^
  : Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
  .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
  ^
  : Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
  import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/lasthoney/development_setup/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/lasthoney/development_setup/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

the error source is not the `flutter pub get` itself, as I see it does get the dependencies as expected, if you didn't really have an error in your code, then try running:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

then run/build your app again.

Comment: try this but showing error of material_bottom_sheet,file and many more.

Comment: I guess you need to include those errors